# How to create android admob

Tags: android

I am new in android how to create the admob and how to it work.

```
<com.google.ads.AdView               
       android:id="@+id/ad"
       android:layout_width="800dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId=""   
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" 
        >             
 </com.google.ads.AdView>
```

I try this but not work.

Comment: Just try to search it on google, you will have lots of tutorials

Comment: follow this tutorial:http://androidforbegineers.blogspot.in/2013/08/android-admob-sample-code.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"     


<com.google.ads.AdView               
       android:id="@+id/ad"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ur admob id"   
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" 
        >             
 </com.google.ads.AdView>
```

and give the permission